# Count multiple values of a dataframe across all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I count the occurrences of multiple values within the entire data frame? Is there a way to achieve without a for loop?

Ex = count all 0's and -1's in all columns of the data frame

I was thinking something like df.apply.count(0,-1)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 3):

Simple using `melt` with `value_counts`

```
df.melt().value.value_counts()
```

Or

```
np.unique(a.values.ravel(),return_counts=True)
Out[292]: (array([1, 2, 3, 5], dtype=int64), array([3, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(range(-2, 3), size=(10, 10)),
    columns=[*'abcdefghij']
)

df

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0 -2  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1 -2
1  0 -2 -2  2 -2  0  0 -2  2 -1
2  1  0  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  2
3  1 -1  1 -2  2  2  0  0 -2  0
4  2 -2  2 -1  2  2  0  0 -2  0
5  2  1 -1  2  0  2  0  1  2  1
6 -2  1  1 -1 -2 -2  2  1 -2  2
7 -1  1  2  0  2 -2 -2  0 -2  2
8  2  1 -2  1 -1 -1  2  1  2  1
9 -1  1  2 -2  1  0 -2 -2  1 -1
```

#### `numpy.in1d`

This should be very fast

```
np.in1d(df.values, [0, -1]).sum()

29
```

---

#### @SandeepKadapa

similar performance to `np.in1d(df.values, [0, -1]).sum()`

```
np.isin(df.values.ravel(),[0,-1]).sum()

29
```

---

#### `numpy.in1d` with `np.count_nonzero`

This should be very fast(er)

```
np.count_nonzero(np.in1d(df.values, [0, -1]))

29
```

---

#### `applymap` + `set.__contain__` + `numpy.sum`

This is a bit cheeky

```
df.applymap({0, -1}.__contains__).values.sum()

29
```

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(np.in1d(df.values, [0, -1]))` is the fastest of all the solutions provided.

Comment: Also, add `np.isin(df.values.ravel(),[0,-1]).sum()` this performs almost identical to `np.in1d(df.values, [0, -1]).sum()`

Comment: I imagine it is doing much the same thing under the hood (-:

Comment: Not sure the core functionality, I just suggested to not leave any possible numpy based solutions for reference.